# What may cause Column not found (nid) in on clause?

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n, database

I'm using Drupal 7.14 and Entity API and Reference 1.0-rc3.

And I'm also using i18n, entityreference (not References) and field_sql_storage.

I get this error when saving a node that has some custom fields using references.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'field_data_body0.nid' in 'on clause': SELECT
>   field_data_body0.entity_type AS entity_type,
>   field_data_body0.entity_id AS entity_id, field_data_body0.revision_id
>   AS revision_id, field_data_body0.bundle AS bundle FROM
>   {field_data_body} field_data_body0 INNER JOIN {node} node ON
>   field_data_body0.nid = node.nid WHERE (field_data_body0.deleted =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (field_data_body0.entity_type =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (field_data_body0.bundle IN
>   (:db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3)) AND
>   (field_data_body0.entity_id IN (:db_condition_placeholder_4)) AND
>   (node.language IN (:db_condition_placeholder_5,
>   :db_condition_placeholder_6)) ORDER BY field_data_body0.body_value
>   ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 0
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => node [:db_condition_placeholder_2] =>
>   news [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => page
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => 25 [:db_condition_placeholder_5] =>
>   it [:db_condition_placeholder_6] => und ) in
>   field_sql_storage_field_storage_query() (linea 577 di
>   /home/morpheu5/web/xdatanet/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).

What bothers me is that, first of all there's a zero appended to the name of the table, and second, if I add that nid column to that table, Drupal is happy and everything seems to work.

I suspect there must have been some update gone horribly wrong, since maintenance is not under my control, and I had to implement some new features working on my local copy which at that time was already completely out of sync with the client's staging and production servers.

I tried a number of patches, and I've gone through the code myself but I'm not **this** familiar with Drupal.

**EDIT**

It seems the nid column is getting added at some point in `function preExecute` in `includes/database/select.inc` specifically at row 1236

```
drupal_alter($hooks, $query);
```

the hooks acting here are

- `query`
- `query_entity_field_access`
- `query_node_access`
- `query_entityreference`

but after a hour long investigation I only came up with a huge headache, and I'm still not sure if I actually found and debugged all of those hooks. As far as I could see, the `nid` column is not present before the drupal_alter call while it is after, but it's there at the beginning of each hook_query_TAG_alter I was able to find.

I must be missing something.

**EDIT 2**

The culprit seems to be `i18n`, specifically `i18n_select`, more specifically at row 137 of `i18n_select.module` where it adds the `nid` column.

**EDIT 3**

There, I opened a bug: https://drupal.org/node/1679646

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago and I think the problem was with the `references` module. You should have a look at this http://drupal.org/node/1275096. There is a patch called `column_not_found_1054_unkonw_column-1275096-8.patch` which solved my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using the `references` module but the `entityreference` one. I tried looking at that patch but it didn't seem like it could be translated.

Answer (score 0):

The body field should definitively NOT have a `nid` column in the table. The `field_data_body` table provided by core will contain an `entity_id` column which is the reference to the node entity.

2 things I can think of that might be causing this:

1. You have custom code that's making an erroneous database query in a `hook_node_load()` function or similar (either directly or using an `EntityFieldQuery`)
2. (more likely I think) Core/contributed modules or files have been edited and the changes are only now causing problems.

The best advice I can give is to install the [Hacked!](http://drupal.org/project/hacked/) module and determine whether or not core/contributed modules have indeed been hacked. If that comes back all clear then you're just looking at an error in some custom code somewhere which will be easy to track down.

If it doesn't come back clear, at least you know what the problem is and you can then decide how best to proceed with getting Drupal back into a proper un-hacked state.

Incidentally, don't worry about the table being referred to as `field_data_body0`...if you look further down in the query that's just an alias that's being used for `field_data_body`:

```
FROM {field_data_body} field_data_body0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know. That Hacked! module is completely new to me :)

Comment: Apparently neither the core nor contributed modules have been modified significantly: just a couple of completely unrelated lines but I managed to get them back in place and the error is still there. I also have a couple of custom modules made using Features and, as far as I know but I can't be 100% sure, this problem started after they installed these two modules I made. Neither of these appear to reference anything related to nid, though.

Comment: I updated the question.